# A question in theorem related to basis in Topology

Tags: general-topology

I am self studying Topology from "Foundations of Topology" from Wayne Patty and I have a question in Theorem 1.11 on page 19.

It's image:

[image]

How does in last line of  proof T'=T? ( I have no problem in understanding anything before it). How to deduce it?

Comment: It says $\mathcal T'$ is  finer  than $\mathcal T$ by Theorem 1.9.

Comment: The statement that $\mathscr{T}'$ is finer than $\mathscr{T}$ means precisely that $\mathscr{T}\subseteq\mathscr{T}'$. Combine that with the fact that $\mathscr{T}'\subseteq\mathscr{T}$, and you have the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says before: $\mathcal{T}'$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}$, which means

$$\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}'$$

Then he derives that also

$$\mathcal{T}' \subseteq \mathcal{T}$$

and when two sets are subsets of each other they are equal (simple set theory) so

$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}'$$ follows.